# What is the extent to which Malcolm X's activism was influenced by his Muslim beliefs?

Tags: religion, islam, north-america, race, civil-rights

Have been researching the role of religion on the Civil Rights movement and while I am aware that Malcolm X identified as a Muslim it is unclear as to how this belief influenced his (and his supporters') work as an activist. Was simply wondering whether there are any interpretations or recommended texts on the subject.

Comment: I think this question should be asked on [Islam Beta Stack Exchange](http://islam.stackexchange.com/questions). I recommend you watch the movie. I watched it several times and I think it could help you. BTW, your question is too broad to be answered definitively.

Comment: @Rathony thanks, I think I will ask there and while my question is pretty broad was just hoping for some potential suggestions.

Comment: Always my pleasure. One thing you should note is the narrower your question is, the higher chances that you will get a high-quality answer. And don't expect too much.

Comment: Please delete any discussion in comments; comments are not for extended discussion or discussion of topics other than the question.

Comment: Be careful with this question.  The Islam Stack Exchange, for instance, would probably not be a good place to go.  The [Nation of Islam](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nation_of_Islam) would be considered, at best, a VERY idiosyncratic version of mainstream Islam.  Malcom X was a member of the Nation of Islam up to 1964, Sunni Muslim thereafter up until his assassination in 1965.  You won't get anywhere as long as you conflate early Nation of Islam with mainstream Islam.

Comment: @AlaskaRon Thanks for the tip, found this issue to be the main barrier in my understanding as despite quite a lot being a written on what the Nation of Islam did, I have found very little on how Islamic the organisation actually was, it might be more useful for me to ask how the Nation of Islam was influenced by Islam, rather than Malcolm X.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Malcolm X's understanding of race was [dramatically changed](http://www.telegraph.co.uk/news/worldnews/middleeast/saudiarabia/1387524/Mecca-made-Malcolm-X-change.html) by his completion of the Hajj, the Muslim pilgrimage to Mecca. [Here's](http://momentsintime.com/the-most-remarkable-revelatory-letter-ever-written-by-malcolm-x/) a copy of the letter he wrote. He wrote that,

> "I have never before witnessed such sincere hospitality and the
>   practice of true brotherhood as I have seen it here in Arabia. In fact
>   all I have seen and experienced on this pilgrimage as forced me to
>   're-arrange' much of thoughts pattern and to toss aside some of my
>   previous conclusions....I have eaten. From the same plate...with
>   fellow Muslims whose skin was the whitest of white, whose eyes was the
>   bluest of blue, and whose hair was the blondest of blond – I could
>   look into their blue eyes and see that they regarded me as the same
>   (Brothers), because their faith in One God (Allah) had actually
>   removed “white” from their mind,....If white Americans could accept
>   the religion of Islam, if they could accept the Oneness of God (Allah)
>   they too could then sincerely accept the Oneness of Men, and cease to
>   measure others always in terms of their 'difference in color'."

At this point, his attitude changed from a perspective of an innate conflict between black people and white people to a viewpoint in which black people and white people could get along.